# Creating a recursive geometric sequence function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def geo():
    start = int(input()) # starting number
    multiplier = int(input()) # the multiplier
    length = int(input()) # how long the list should be
    for i in range(length):
        x = start * multiplier ** i
        print(x, "", end = "")
    print()
```

I need to create a recursive geometric function based off user input. I know how to approach it non-recursively but how do I approach it recursively? Thanks in advance.

i.e: if the user inputs

```
start = 1
multiplier = 2
length = 5
Output: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
```

Edit: thanks for all the examples guys, I understand how recursion a lot better now.

Comment: Please add examples showing the types of inputs you expect and the type of output you would like to achieve.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do this recursively? What would be the advantage to a method you have at hand?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
You should be able to show us your attempt at recursion, with a *specific* problem in syntax or result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the for loop.
Instead of it call the function recursively with a decrement in the argument.
Create a function with an integer as parameter and call it every time until a condition is met.

```
 def geo(start, multiplier, length, i=0):

      if length <= 0:
           exit()    #or use a return statement

      x = start * multiplier ** i 
      print(x, "", end = "") 
      print()

      geo(start, multiplier, length-1, i+1)

 start = int(input()) 
 multiplier = int(input())
 length = int(input()) 
 i=0
 geo(start, multiplier, length, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a loop that you want to turn into a recursive function:

```
for i in range(length):
    x = start * multiplier ** i
```

what you need to do is:

1. have a stop condition (`i < length`)
2. if stop condition is not met -> call again with the next value

do this before the function, because you'll need this value

```
length = int(input()) # how long the list should be 
start = int(input()) # starting number 
multiplier = int(input()) # the multiplier

def recursive_geo(i):
    # stop condition
    if i == length:
        return 1 # since the value will be multiplied by the previous values, you don't want to use 0 or any other value
    else:
        print(x, "", end = "")
        print()
        return start * multiplier ** i * recursive_geo(i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With any recursive function you need a base case and a general (recursion) case.

Let's start with your current code to get the inputs, but instead of calculating the value immediately we'll call a recursive function.

```
def geo():

    start = int(input()) # starting number
    multiplier = int(input()) # the multiplier
    length = int(input()) # how long the list should be
    result = geo_rec(start, multiplier, length)
    print(result)


def geo_rec(start, multiplier, length):

    print(start) # As per your current program

    # Base case check
    if length = 0:
        return start

    # Recursive case
    else:
        start = start * multiplier
        length = length - 1
        geo_rec(start, multiplier, length)
```

Now consider, if length is 0 what will we get? We will just get start - that's good. If length = 1, we'll recurse one level, and then return start (which by this point will be our original start * multiplier) - also good.

Notice with each run of the recursive case we work our way progressively to the base case?